# Error in loading image

Tags: java, image-processing

Following is the code to load image from the project folder itself.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        File f = new File("StegImg.png");
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try{
               img = ImageIO.read(f);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("The image height is " + img.getHeight());
    }
```

I have used this code many times, but can't figure out the problem.
The error is

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
    at androidsteg.AndroidSteg.main(AndroidSteg.java:26)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at androidsteg.AndroidSteg.main(AndroidSteg.java:32)
```

The image is indeed a valid image like [image]

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the correct file when creating your File object? Try to do some debugging to make sure that the File object you create is using the right pathname.

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure but I think the problem is maybe in path of your image
so maybe you should provide a path like `C:/Users/Desktop/StegImg.png`
or maybe you just mispelled image name ..
hope that helps